# Problemas con datos de formulario en la vista CreateView - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, djangorestframework, django-views

Tengo un problema interesante, primero que nada el modelo como tal:

```
class Reserva(models.Model):
    cliente = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    empleado_de_turno = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

El problema consiste:

> Crear una instancia del modelo `Reserva` atraves de la vista
>   `CreateView`, el cual creara una formulario para crear dicha
>   instancia, pero en el formulario no quiero que se muestre el campo
>   `empleado_de_turno` quiero que solo se muestre el campo `cliente` y
>   que por defecto el valor del campo `empleado_de_turno` sea el usuario
>   que inicio sesión en ese momento.

Bueno para solucionar dicho problema, intente modificando los datos enviados por el método POST, en el método `get_form_kwargs`:

```
class ReservaCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Reserva
    template_name = 'testapp1/example.html'
    fields = ['cliente']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        if form_kwargs.get('data'):
            user = User.objects.get(username = self.request.user)
            post = self.request.POST.copy()
            post['empleado_de_turno'] = str(user.pk)
            form_kwargs['data'] = post

        return form_kwargs
```

El caso es que no me funciona, siempre me sale este error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: testapp1_reserva.empleado_de_turno_id
```

Comencé a tratar de averiguar donde exactamente ocurría el error, porque la solución del método `get_form_kwargs` que mostré antes, debería solucionar el error, y el error ocurre en el método `form_valid`, específicamente en el `form.save()`, aquí el código fuente del método `form_valid`:

> **ModelFormMixin:**
>
> ```
>  def form_valid(self, form):
>      """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
>      self.object = form.save()
>      return super().form_valid(form)
> ```
>
> **FormMixin:**
>
> ```
> def form_valid(self, form):
>     """If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL."""
>     return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
> ```

---

> **IMPORTANTE**
>
> Lo siguiente lo hice con la intención de ver como es la estructura de los datos cuando se creaba la instancia, sin omitir campos y cuando
>   se omitía el campo `empleado_de_turno`, para así poder replicar la
>   estructura al momento de omitir dicho campo y al momento de modificar
>   dichos datos, y así poder solucionar el problema, evitando errores

### Caso 1:

En el método `form_valid`, imprimí `form.data` cuando en el atributo `fields` tenia el siguiente valor:

```
fields = ['cliente']
```

### Caso 2:

Después hice los mismo pero en este caso el atributo `fields` tenia los siguientes valores:

```
fields = ['cliente', 'empleado_de_turno']
```

---

Imprimí de la siguiente manera en el método `form_valid` los datos, ya que aquí era donde específicamente surgía el error y cabía la posibilidad de que los datos no se estuvieran enviado como yo los modifique anteriormente:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    print(form.data)
```

El resultado de imprimirlo en los **2 casos** fue el siguiente:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['SBRSJa0aw4iNJOMPwtQVsFL6V6y1cFMNGne9Kr0fA7YmtYeD8xshhDq6pc1mKjQs'], 'cliente': ['code2'], 'empleado_de_turno': ['1']}>
```

Eso quiere decir que ya sea que imprima `form.data` en el **Caso 1** o en el **Caso 2**, los datos son exactamente iguales, lo cual significa que el problema no son los datos al momento de modificarlos, es algo mas (deduzco yo).

Ya que incluso al momento de imprimir `form.is_valid` en el método `form_valid`, da como resultado `True`.

Entonces **¿Porque da error, si estoy replicando la estructura de los datos correctamente al modificarlo?** No le encuentro sentido a dicho error, todo el proceso de modificación lo estoy haciendo correctamente.

---

### Actualización:

Muchos piensan que en realidad el campo `empleado_de_turno` espera en el `form` o en la vista un objeto, yo envió un `id` y pueden pensar que ese es el error, pero no es así.

**Primero que nada, ya lo intente, en ves de poner un `id` en el campo `empleado_de_turno`, puse un objeto, y daba el mismo error.**

La razón de que el campo `empleado_de_turno` espera un `id` y no un objeto es porque así es como lo gestiona la vista, por lo menos al momento de recibir los datos por el método POST, no se porque lo gestiona así, así es como lo decidieron los desarrolladores de `Django`.

Esto se puede comprobar en el **Caso 2**, no se omite ningún campo, se rellenan los dos campos con normalidad y se imprime en el método `form_valid` los datos ingresados de la siguiente manera: `form.data`.

Al imprimirlo da como resultado:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['SBRSJa0aw4iNJOMPwtQVsFL6V6y1cFMNGne9Kr0fA7YmtYeD8xshhDq6pc1mKjQs'], 'cliente': ['code2'], 'empleado_de_turno': ['1']}>
```

Claramente se puede observar que la `key` `empleado_de_turno` tiene como valor un `id`, no un objeto.

Ahí se puede comprobar que el campo `empleado_de_turno` no espera un objeto como tal, por lo menos no en esa etapa de la vista.

Comment: Imprimí  `form.errors` tal como dices, y no imprime nada. Es imposible que se pierdan los datos al hacer el POST pues de eso se trata, de que el campo `empleado_de_turno` ya tenga por defecto el `user` loggeado, por eso mismo modifico los datos en el método `get_form_kwargs`.

Comment: Eso ya lo intente y sigue dando el mismo error. La estructura del `request.POST`, el valor del campo `empleado_de_turno` no es un objeto como tal, es un id, de tipo `str`. No estas leyendo todo el problema, todo esto ya lo explico y narro como trato de solucionar el problema.

Comment: Mi duda es ¿Porque el error?, no una alternativa. Me explico?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96323/discussion-between-jacknavarow-and-julio-cesar).

Comment: En el error pone "empleado_de_turno_id" mientras que en el ejemplo pone "empleado_de_turno" ¿puede ser que en la bd lo tengas de una forma y en el formulario de otra? o que en la bd estén ambos

Comment: No te entiendo, exprésate con mas detalles.

Comment: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: testapp1_reserva.empleado_de_turno_id <-- **aqui es empleado_de_turno_id**

En el resto del ejemplo, el campo se llama **empleado_de_turno**

Comment: Interesante, lo acabo de intentar, cambiando `empleado_de_turno` por `empleado_de_turno_id` y sale exactamente el mismo error...

Comment: revisa la base de datos, si por algún motivo tienes una columna empleado_de_turno y otra empleado_de_turno_id puede darte un error casi identico y la vista jugarte una mala pasada

Comment: Ya revise y si existe una columna llamada `empleado_de_turno_id`,y no existe una columna llamada `empleado_de_turno`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96521/discussion-between-durgeoble-and-julio-cesar).

Comment: Yo creo que el problema puede ser porque el formulario busca el initial data y el get_form_kwargs no se lo provee o se lo da vacio.

Comment: Por favor no coloques en el título de tu pregunta leyendas como no resuelto, puedes esperar a la ayuda, editar para mejorar la pregunta u ofrecer una recompensa de tu reputación para atraer mas atención a tu publicación

Comment: OK no sabia sobre ello :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Marcelo dice lo siguiente en su respuesta (gracias a el pude encontrar la respuesta):

> *Intentando replicar tu problema llegué a este método (haciendo referencia al método `get_form_kwargs`), solo acepta las
>   fields que declaras en la view, este caso solo será cliente:*
>
> (lo cual no es cierto, el "que no acepta los `fields`" es el form, no el método o la vista).

Lo que me llamo la atención fue que dijo "solo acepta los fields que declaras en la view" como consecuencia me puse a investigar el código fuente de la vista `CreateView`, pero no encontré nada respecto a lo que decía, como tenia que ver con el atributo `fields` (como mencionaba), entonces tenia que ver mas con los formularios, el caso es llege investigar el código fuente
del [`BaseModelForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L280).

(Cabe recalcar que si no definimos el atributo `form_class` en la vista, con el form, el método [`get_form_class`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_form_class), de la vista, se encarga de crearlo automáticamente, justamente pasandole el atributo `fields` definido en la vista, al formulario)

Y encontré la respuesta al *"¿Porque sucede el error?"*, a continuación explicare mas a profundidad como sucede esto y porque sucede el problema:

Todo comienza al momento de ejecutarse el método `is_valid` en la vista (específicamente en el método [`post`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#post) de la vista), dicho método llama al método **`Form.full_clean`**, que a su ves llama a los siguientes métodos (para hacer las respectivas validaciones):

- `_clean_fields`
- `_clean_form`
- `_post_clean`

Cuando es llamado el método [`_post_clean`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L383), en una parte se encarga de validar la instancia, donde se puede ver como llama al método **`Model.full_clean`** de la instancia, pasadole los campos excluidos del método `_get_validation_exclusions`:

> ```
> def _post_clean(self):
>     opts = self._meta
>
>     exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()
>
>     ...
>
>     try:
>         self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
>     except ValidationError as e:
>         self._update_errors(e)
>
>     ...
> ```
>
> **¿Que es lo que hace el método [`_get_validation_exclusions`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L310)?**
>
> Dicho método se encarga recolectar los campos que van ha ser excluidos
>   según ciertas validaciones, añadiendo los nombres de dichos campos a
>   una variable llamada `exclude`, para posteriormente retornarla.
>
> Aquí un fragmento de código, donde añade los nombres de los campos que
>   no están en el atributo `fields` del formulario a la variable
>   `exclude` (este es la razón especifica del porque no se guardaba la
>   instancia):
>
> > ```
> > ...
> > for f in self.instance._meta.fields:
> >     field = f.name
> >     # Exclude fields that aren't on the form. The developer may be
> >     # adding these values to the model after form validation.
> >     if field not in self.fields:
> >         exclude.append(f.name)
> > ...
> > ```

Una ves llamado el método **`Model.full_clean`** de la instancia, este llama al método [`Model.clean_fields`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L1229) de la instancia (entre otros), pasandole como parámetro los campos excluidos, de esta manera el método `Model.clean_fields`, **solo crea los atributos validos, no los excluidos**:

> ```
> def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
>     """
>     Clean all fields and raise a ValidationError containing a dict
>     of all validation errors if any occur.
>     """
>     if exclude is None:
>         exclude = []
>
>     errors = {}
>     for f in self._meta.fields:
>         if f.name in exclude:
>             continue
>         # Skip validation for empty fields with blank=True. The developer
>         # is responsible for making sure they have a valid value.
>         raw_value = getattr(self, f.attname)
>         if f.blank and raw_value in f.empty_values:
>             continue
>         try:
>             setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self)) # <---
>         except ValidationError as e:
>             errors[f.name] = e.error_list
>
>     ...
> ```

Y listo, el método `is_valid` retorna `True` (pero ya hicieron las respectivas validaciones), y se procede a crear la instancia en el método `ModelForm.save`:

> ```
> def save(self, commit=True):
>     ...
>     if commit:
>         # If committing, save the instance and the m2m data immediately.
>         self.instance.save()
>         self._save_m2m()
>     else:
>         # If not committing, add a method to the form to allow deferred
>         # saving of m2m data.
>         self.save_m2m = self._save_m2m
>     return self.instance
> ```

Pero como se ejecutaron las validaciones, pues no se crea el atributo `empleado_de_turno_id` a pesar de haberlo añadido en los datos POST y como consecuencia ocurre el error, impidiendo la creación de la instancia al momento de que el método `form_valid` de la vista, intenta crearla.

Answer (score 8):

Soy el que te inspiro a profundizarte en esta pregunta jeje, ya encontré una solución al parecer mas prolija que me anda de lujo:

```
class ReservaCreate(CreateView):
    model = Reserva
    fields = ['cliente']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        reserva = form.save(commit=False)
        reserva.empleado_de_turno = self.request.user
        reserva.save()
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

Saludo grande!!

Comment: Pues si, incluso me parece una forma mas elegante y limpia tu solución, pero bueno, mi duda como tal es a que se debe el error. Saludos!!

Comment: ¿A que se debe el error?, me parece que es principalmente lo que pregunta el OP.

Answer (score 0):

Intentando replicar tu problema llegué a este método, solo acepta las fields que declaras en la view, este caso solo será cliente:

```py
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    """Return the keyword arguments for instantiating the form."""
    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    if hasattr(self, 'object'):
        kwargs.update({'instance': self.object})
    return kwargs
```

Esto lo puedes verificar con esto:

```py
class ReservaCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Reserva
    template_name = 'reservas/create.html'
    fields = ['cliente']

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        if form_kwargs.get('data'):
            user = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user)
            form_kwargs['empleado_de_turno'] = str(user.pk)
        return form_kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.data)
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Obtendrás el siguiente error:

```sh
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'empleado_de_turno'
```

Cuando usas:

```py
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    form_kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    if form_kwargs.get('data'):
        user = User.objects.get(username = self.request.user)
        post = self.request.POST.copy()
        post['empleado_de_turno'] = str(user.pk)
        form_kwargs['data'] = post
    return form_kwargs
```

Este método simplemente sobreescribe `form_kwargs` e ignora  `empleado_de_turno`, lo mismo pasa en `form_valid` que solo validará lo que declaraste en fields.

Por eso te recomiendo usar lo que señala la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user):

```py
class ReservaCreate(CreateView):
    model = Reserva
    fields = ['cliente']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.empleado_de_turno = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Mi pregunta es: **¿Porque el error?**, no una "alternativa" al intento de solución que estoy empleando. Puede que haya mejores formas de hacerlo, pero mi pregunta es por que sucede el error?, dicha pregunta surge en un intento de solucionar el problema, ya planteado en mi pregunta.

Comment: En esta actualización intento explicarte el error, no soy muy bueno para explicar pero creo que se entiende.

Comment: Marcelo, gracias a tu respuesta es que pude encontrar la respuesta a mi pregunta! pero lo que dices no es cierto, el que "no acepta los fields que declaras en la view" por así decirlo, es el form, no el método o la vista. Publique una respuesta explicándolo, échale un vistaso.

Comment: En mi respuesta digo "solo acepta las fields que declaras en la view", pero me alegro que de algo sirva mi respuesta. En este caso ambos aprendimos, saludos.

Comment: Si fue de gran ayuda! Pense que jamas se resolveria esta pregunta, era solo cuestion de leer el codigo fuente, Saludos!